# Help me find the PSPICE error, please!

Tags: simulation, spice, pspice, model

I am trying to simulate the frequency response of a buck converter with the specific tantalum caps that I will be using on my board. The goal is to evaluate stability (phase margin).

The capacitor OEM provides SPICE models for this purpose, but I have been unable to import them successfully into either PSPICE or TINA TI - both give variations of the same error.

```
.SUBCKT CAP_PN n1 n2

*parasitic inductance
Lesl n1 2 2.500000E-009
Rels n1 2 1.000000E+001

*leakage current & reverse bias effects
Rp 2 n2 3.333333E+005
Dp n2 2 1.000000E-001

*RC-ladder model of frequency effects
R1 2 3 6.577619E-002
C1 2 3 2.018395E-002
R2 3 4 1.564400E-002
C2 4 n2 1.071244E-005
R3 4 5 6.053062E-004
C3 5 n2 2.142487E-005
R4 5 6 6.484084E-004
C4 6 n2 4.284975E-005
R5 6 7 7.212317E-003
C5 7 n2 8.569949E-005
R6 7 8 4.670830E-002
C6 8 n2 1.713990E-004

.ENDS
```

The problem appears to be associated with the Dp component.

[image: TINA_TI_Error]

[image: PSPICE_Error]

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with this model? I've been banging my head up against this for several days. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you reverse biasing the capacitor? If not then remove the Dp line.

Comment: @Andyaka
Thanks for the suggestion. I am not reverse biasing the cap and removing the Dp line got everything to work!

Answer (score 5):

A "D" element is a diode, and needs 2 terminals and a model name (at least). The syntax shown is incorrect for a diode.

Comment: I suspect it was a typo and they meant to write `Cp`. Or maybe it was a diode plus a capacitor, for the reverse bias. But, it doesn't matter, because that means the model has not even been tested, so I'd be cautious.

Comment: @jde0503 What is the nominal value of your tantalum capacitor?  If that line was supposed to be for a 100mF capacitor and that's what your tantalum is listed as, then removing that line gets rid of your primary component of the model.

Comment: odd that the simulator converts the syntax to a number before attempting to look up a model with that name

Comment: Yes, weird parser for the simulator !

Answer (score 3):

Are you reverse biasing the capacitor? If not then remove the Dp line.

> *@Andyaka Thanks for the suggestion. I am not reverse biasing the cap
> and removing the Dp line got everything to work! – jde0503*

Job done then!